# How to set return message on save success using sigma grid?

Tags: jquery, sigma-grid-control

does anyone know, how to set return message when using sigma grid??

i've read the documentation on http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_grid2/docs/

however still no luck, i don't really understand how to use it

maybe anyone can solve this mistery?? :D
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly? I am getting somewhere with Sigma grid. 
The Controller.php example is quite helpful; it shows how the response comes back to the Sigma grid javascript in JSON format for actioning.